# Append extra zeroes to decimal to make 4.5 look 4.500 but 4.5234 should be 4.5234

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a value fetched from the database, it's like:

```
4.5   which should be 4.500
0.01  which should be 0.010
11    which should be 11.000
```

so I used this piece of code

```
sprintf("%.3f",(double)$html['camp_cpc'])
```

But here arised another problem. If `$html['camp_cpc'] = '4.5234'`, then also it displays `4.523` instead of original value `4.5234`

Also for other values with larger decimal like `0.346513`, its only showing up to `0.346`.

How can I solve this problem in JavaScript also?

Comment: solve it only in Javascript, is a data showing problem, not server side

Comment: That javascript portion really should be in it's own separate question as it's unrelated (even then, this is easy to Google)

Comment: $foo = "105";
echo number_format((float)$foo, 3, '.', '');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, use `%0.3f` — and you don't need to cast as `(double)`

```
<?php
echo sprintf("%0.3f", 4.5);    // "4.500"
echo sprintf("%0.3f", 4.5234); // "4.523"
```

If you want to display 4 decimal places, use `%0.4f`

```
echo sprintf("%0.4f", 4.5);    // "4.5000"
echo sprintf("%0.4f", 4.5234); // "4.5234"
```

---

To do this in JavaScript

```
(4.5).toFixed(3); // "4.500"
```

Comment: you are not getting the point Sir/Madam.... i need to show upto 3 decimal places when no. of digits(after zero) is less than 3. Else I need to show the original no. The procedure you stated meant that I need to use "%0.4f" for upto 4 decimal places

Answer (score 2):

Floats `4.5` and `4.500` correspond to the same number, so they cannot (and should not) be used/stored in a way that preserves the different representation. If you need to preserve the original representation given by a user, you need to store this field as a list (string) and convert to a float whenever you need the float value

Comment: I am not storing in the DB, i just want to display it in the textbox... If i enter 4.5000 then also in mysql, it will be stored as 4.5(if defined as datatype float)

Comment: @Saswat - That's the generic suggestion. I mean you'll need to use string datatype in any language  to display it with multiple zeros at the end of  fractional part

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript at least, this is an implementation of what I think you want:

```
function getValue(x, points) {
    var str = x.toString();
    // Convert to string
    var idx = str.indexOf(".");
    // If the number is an integer
    if(!~idx) return str + "." + "0".repeat(points);
    // Get the tail of the number
    var end = str.substr(idx+1);
    // If the tail exceeds the number of decimal places, return the full string
    if(end.length > points) return str;
    // Otherwise return the int + the tail + required number of zeroes
    return str.substr(0, idx) + "." + end.substr(0, points) + "0".repeat(points-end.length);
}
console.log(getValue(4.5, 3)); //4.500
console.log(getValue(0.01, 3)); //0.010
console.log(getValue(11, 3)); //11.000
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0njtp0k5/) (Makes use of ES6 [String.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) for demonstration purposes)

The important thing to note here is that this is *string manipulation*. Once you start to say "I want the number to look like..." it's no longer a number, it's what you want to show the user.

This takes your number, converts it to the string and pads the end of the string with the appropriate number of zeroes. If the decimal exceeds the number of places required the full number is returned.

Answer (score 0):

It could look sth. like this:

```
var n = [4.5234, 0.5, 0.11, 456.45];
var temp_n;

for(var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    temp_n = String(n[i]).split(".");
    if(temp_n[1] == null || temp_n[1].length < 3) {
        n[i] = n[i].toFixed(3); 
    }
}
```